# Memory slicing error in glib-2.0

Tags: c++11, gtk, glib, gtkmm3

I've encountered a bug in my Gtkmm-3.0 application that seems to be memory related from my quick google search, but I've been unable to tease out a possible cause. The application will fail at random, and I've removed all the code that gets updated during each call to signal_timeout() with no effect. It doesn't seem to be related to key/button presses either.

Valgrind has been less than helpful since the GUI takes ages to spin up. Any advice from either a Gtk/Glib user, or someone who's run into this error before would be greatly appreciated. Below is the stack trace from my most recent core file.

```
(gdb) bt
    #0  0x00007f4b5de27720 in magazine_cache_push_magazine () at /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
    #1  0x00007f4b5de278e2 in private_thread_memory_cleanup () at /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
    #2  0x00007f4b5a6b6c22 in __nptl_deallocate_tsd () at /lib64/libpthread.so.0
    #3  0x00007f4b5a6b6e33 in start_thread () at /lib64/libpthread.so.0
    #4  0x00007f4b5cabf34d in clone () at /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s almost certainly a heap corruption bug in your application or one of the libraries it uses, rather than a bug in GLib. The only real way to debug these issues is using Valgrind. Make sure you run it with `G_SLICE=always-malloc` set in the environment, as that will disable GSlice and use `malloc()` instead, which Valgrind can instrument better.

If Valgrind really won’t work for your application, you could try the simpler glibc heap consistency checks, enabled by setting `MALLOC_CHECK_=1` in the environment: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Heap-Consistency-Checking.html#Heap-Consistency-Checking

Comment: I stripped it down to the absolute bare minimum, and actually got Valgrind to run in a reasonable amount of time. I may have gotten lucky, but I did find a spot where I could be writing data to a stale pointer from time to time. The basics win again. This is my first time using Gtk though, so I'll keep the other tips around for future reference.